# Running AmazonS3Client from JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services, jboss, amazon-s3

I am trying to run the Amazon AWS S3 example code on JBoss. It runs fine as a JSE app. I add the same amazon dependency to my POM in both projects. The call to instantiate teh client always throws an exception when running on JBoss

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 conn = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

Throws this exception:

> NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory

I think this is related to the http-client.jar but I have no idea how  to fix this, tell JBoss where to pick up the correct dependency etc?

ref: http://aws.amazon.com/developers/getting-started/java/

Comment: which version of http-client.jar you are using?

Comment: httpclinet 4.1.2 (with the SchemeSocketFactory class) exists in /JBOSS_HOME/modules/... Even if i add the jar directly as a dependency to the POM it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix is to add the jar to classpath via Manifest file or jboss-deployment-structure.xml

ref: [Jboss Classloading Explained on Java Code Geeks](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/jboss-as-7-classloading-explained.html)